# How to attach new EBS volume to Ubuntu machine on AWS?

Tags: 11.04, amazon-ec2, aws

Disclaimer: I'm probably missing something obvious, sorry in advance.

I need more EBS disk space for my Ubuntu 11.04 server running on Amazon EC2, and decided to create new volume in addition to the root volume. (It's an EBS-backed instance, created from [official Ubuntu AMIs](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/release/).)

So, I opened AWS management console, created a volume, and attached it to the instance:

[image]

I chose `/dev/sdb` as suggested by the dialog. AWS console shows the volume as correctly attached to the instance.

Problem is, **the device `/dev/sdb` is not available on the instance, not immediately nor after reboot**:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Could not stat /dev/sdb --- No such file or directory
```

Did I miss some necessary step, or is the volume available under some other device name?

(Also tried `/dev/sdc` with same result; `/dev/xvda3` wasn't accepted as "valid EBS device name".)

Comment: I realise there are few AWS questions on Ask Ubuntu, but I thought I'd try here first, as Server Fault hasn't been very good for getting answers...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The devices are named /dev/xvdX rather than sdX in 11.04. This was a kernel change.  The kernel name for xen block devices is 'xvd'.  Previously Ubuntu carried a patch to rename those devices as sdX.  That patch became problematic.

You could, if you really wanted, run your own kernel with a patch applied.
[bug 684875](http://pad.lv/684875) has more information on why this was changed.

So, to answer your question, attach it `/dev/sdb`, it will appear as `/dev/xvdb`.

Comment: Perfect, this solved it! Btw, interestingly, now the "attach volume" dialog has this note (which wasn't there two days ago): "*Newer linux kernels may require you to map your devices to /dev/xvdb through /dev/xvdp instead.*"